# Use of WTF in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, offensive, profanity

I am new to this site and would like to ask whether "WTF" is acceptable in comments or answers?

I found that some users use "WTF" in their comments. Considering the standards and etiquette set by Stack Overflow, can we flag or report such offensive comments to maintain decorum?

Comment: What happens if they're referencing [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)?

Answer (score 5):

Personally I think it's a bit offensive, and tend to flag it because of its tone.

That said, I don't *always* flag it, because WTF has entered the common vernacular, and sometimes its usage is warranted–but it's unduly harsh and doesn't really have a place here.